# In Javascript, how to preventDefault on a child element from within parent event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

Suppose I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

And I have an event handler like this (suppose I have jQuery available):

```
$('div').on('click', function(ev) {
    // ...
});
```

Is it possible, from within that event handler, to prevent the default action of the `<a>` link? Or is it too late? (In other words, am I *required* to attach an event on the `<a>` or lower to prevent the default link action, or is it possible to stop it in the above handler).

As said above, I have jQuery available if the solution requires it.

Comment: Could you check the event.target.nodeName for A vs DIV?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will definitely work:

```
$('div').on('click', "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvKNC/1/

Hold on. this seems to work fine for me in Chrome

```
// prevent default on every click in the div
$('div').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

See the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xvKNC/2/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, delegation will not help in the situation I'm working with (or rather, I can use some complex delegation tricks to work around the issue, but I'm hoping to not have to).

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Maybe you can simplify it somehow?

Comment: My fiddle may be helpful to show the order things happen, because it uses hashchange to detect the links going through.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to work:

```
$('div').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yFfC/